# .net - how to fix my urls?

Tags: .net, relative-path

I have a footer control with the following contents

```
<img src="images/img1.gif" />
<img src="images/img1.gif" />
```

Then I have two pages that include it like so

```
//Default.aspx
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Footer.ascx" TagPrefix="his" TagName="SiteFooter"%>
<his:SiteFooter ID="SiteFooter" runat="server" />

//electronics/Default.aspx
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Footer.ascx" TagPrefix="his" TagName="SiteFooter"%>
<his:SiteFooter ID="SiteFooter" runat="server" />
```

When I view the page in electronics/Default.aspx, the images are broken because the images directory is one directory up.  This project is being served from a virtual path, so web pages will appear with urls such as

```
http://mysite.com/virtualpath/Default.aspx
http://mysite.com/virtualpath/electronics/Default.aspx
```

In PHP, I would prefix those footer images with `<?=PROJECT_URL ?>`.   What is the equivalent approach to this in .net?  Or is there a better way to fix these broken relative paths depending on where you include from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the `img` a aspx control (add `runat="server"`) should allow you to use `~` - try this -

```
<img runat="server" src="~/images/img1.gif" />
<img runat="server" src="~/images/img1.gif" />
```

See [URLs in Master Pages](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/urls-in-master-pages-vb) for details

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="Image1" ImageUrl="~/images/img1.gif" />
<asp:Image runat="server" id="Image2" ImageUrl="~/images/img2.gif" />
```

or

```
<img src="./images/img1.gif" />
<img src="./images/img2.gif" />
```

or

```
<img src="/images/img1.gif" />
<img src="/images/img2.gif" />
```

I found one of the above to always work.

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix is to use the .. to go up one dir before going down into the images folder:

```
<img src="../images/img1.gif" />
```

Comment: but that causes broken images on Default.aspx, even though it fixed electronics/Default.aspx

Comment: Ya, in that case I agree with Scott's answer: